# Find any hard coded values in SQL Server

Tags: select, sql-server-2008-r2, sysobjects

I need to identify any objects in a database containing "scenarioID" that has hard coded value.

I am looking to identify following cases:

1. scenarioId = XX  (two digit value)
2. scenarioId=XX    (two digit value)
3. scenarioId= XX   (two digit value)

Below query I wrote seems to be pulling objects containing "scenarioid", but is giving me more than above cases.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[name]
FROM sysobjects a
INNER JOIN syscomments b on a.id = b.id
WHERE b.[text] LIKE '%scenarioId = __[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: Can you add some data to test on and examples of the false positives you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my mistake.  I was using [^0-9] instead of using [0-9].

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[name]
FROM sysobjects a
INNER JOIN syscomments b on a.id = b.id
WHERE b.[text] LIKE '%scenarioId = [0-9][0-9]%'
or b.[text] like '%scenarioId=[0-9][0-9]%'
or b.[text] like '%scenarioId =[0-9][0-9]%'
or b.[text] like '%scenarioId = [0-9][0-9]%'
or b.[text] like '%scenarioId  = [0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: You could simplify you code by removing the spaces in b.[text] like this...

SELECT DISTINCT a.[name]
FROM sysobjects a
INNER JOIN syscomments b on a.id = b.id
WHERE REPLACE(b.[text], ' ', '') LIKE '%scenarioId=[0-9][0-9]%'